# why use int error,but long long right

Tags: c, long-integer

```
int c;
long long sum=0;
sum+=c*(c-1)/2;
```

when c=100000,why sum can't get the right answer?
should I write
    sum+=(long long)(c*(c-1)/2);

Answer (score 5):

`int` here is 32-bit I assume - 100000 squared (10E9) exceeds the maximum range for an `int` resulting in an overflow.  The below would work - casting the first instance of `c` to `long long` will mean that the rest of the expression will be "long long compatible".

```
sum+=((long long)c*(c-1)/2);
```

Comment: Thank you,I know.Though sum is long long,first c*(c-1)/2 is int(so is overflow),then it is changed to long long.

Comment: My pleasure - that's right, the right-hand side of the += is evalated as int so the overflow occurs before it would be cast to long long.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is using `c` as an `int` in the calculations, and widening it when it's stored.

You need to cast one of the `c`'s to a `long long` before multiplying.

Also, I suggest you look into using `int64_t` in place of `long long` so that you can get the actual type/size you want no matter what (see [stdint.h](http://linux.die.net/man/3/int64_t) for the various identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

In your question c is declared as integer. so it crosses the limit of integer itself in the expression c*(c-1). so overflow occurs.before it gets implicitly converted into long long.Thats the reason behind UB.

whereas when u implicitly converted it into long long u will ger the right answer...